# Powershell ISE opens a cmd prompt when executing a script

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

When I run my scripts from within Powershell ISE, they open up a cmd prompt briefly and then close. The script has successfully executed but I don't even get a chance to see the results before it closes. Optimally I would like to have the output just display in powershell.

This happens with any script I run but here is a basic example that changes to another directory and runs my Postman tests:

```
cd C:\path\to\file\

    .\newman -c "collections\PlatformRelease2.4.json" -e "collections\Platform20Release202.4" -o    "newmanOutput.json"

cd C:\path\to\starting\dir
```

Comment: If you don't show us the script you're using, it's impossible for us to explain why it's not working as you'd like.

Comment: I added a basic script that this happens with. I didn't add it initially because this is happening with every script I try and run. I thought it might be a powershell setting I couldn't find.

Comment: Aren't you specifying that output be redirected to a file with that command? Couldn't you just open the file? Alternatively, if it has on screen feedback try dot sourcing the application.

Comment: Yes, I could look at the output for that specific script but my point was that I don't want the script to run in a separate command prompt. I would like it to run in my current powershell instance.

Comment: bloomm09 - you've shown us how you run the script, not the script itself.  Paste the contents of newman so that folks can help out.  Your code in this script (and presumably other scripts) will likely be the cause.

Comment: That's the thing. My script is literally just changing directories and calling newman. I feel like this is some switch in powershell that got flipped because I was previously able to just run that exact script and have it display in my current powershell instance rather than popping up a cmd window while it executes and then closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Newman is a command-line collection runner for Postman. You are executing a third party **command-line** program which opens a command prompt.

Try

```
Invoke-Expression '.\newman -c "collections\PlatformRelease2.4.json" -e "collections\Platform20Release202.4" -o "newmanOutput.json"'
```